# Ubuntu is not booting up after installing

Tags: system-installation

Ubuntu is not booting up. I just installed ubuntu and after installing,it told to restart the computer so i did but it shows hp logo and then it shows black screen with white text that says  restart system and again it shows hp logo. It repeats on and on.
Edit- I installed Ubuntu 22.04lts on a hp ProBook 440 g1

Comment: Please be specific as to what Ubuntu product & release you installed.  Details about your hardware, and your install are also helpful (*what architecture? is this the only OS on your system?, dual boot? encryption used etc*)

Comment: Yes, this is the only os in my system